# Hide only menu for specific users odoo 11

Tags: menu, rules, odoo-11

How can I hide the menus to specific employees the menus are :

ODOO Menu :

-Employee
-Expense
-Holidays

I want the "Attendances" menu that will be displayed for specific users

Answer (score 0):

Login with `admin` credentials, activate developer menu from settings, go to `Technical > Menu Items (Under User Interface Sections)` Search for those menu items by name and open required menu item. Click on edit, on `Access Rights` tab, add or remove groups to customize the menu permission access to certain group. For example if you want to set permission for this menu only to be accessed by admin user, set the groups permission to `Administration / Settings`. Groups permission on menu items works such way that any one having permission with particular menu item and it's parent item can access that menu. If no group permission is associated with particular menu, that means that particular menu is accessible by all who have permission to parent menu.

Answer (score 0):

Make a new group for menus and gave that group to theses menus so that user belongs to that group will only able to see the menus. The user you want to display the menu gave those user this group.